# What is a useless Constructor in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have two files

```
Description.js and
subjects.js
```

Subject.js file contains an array of subjects

```
export const Subjects=[
{
    id:1,
    title:"Mathematics",
    text:"Cheat Sheet for Mathematics",
    img:"./Images/math.jpg",
},
{
    id:2,
    title:"C-programming",
    text:"Cheat Sheet for C-Programming",
    img:"./Images/cprog.jpg",
},
{
    id:3,
    title:"Physics",
    text:"Cheat Sheet for Physics",
    img:"./Images/physics.jpg",
},
{
    id:4,
    title:"Youtube",
    text:"Recomended Youtube videos for Learning",
    img:"./Images/youtube.jpg",
  },

  ]
```

I want to use this array in Description.js .I'm using a map function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Subjects} from './subjects'

class Description extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render(){
    const description =this.props.Subjects.map((subjects)=>{
    return(
    <h1>{subjects.title}</h1>
    )
    })
return(
    {description}
    )
   }
  }
    export default Description;
```

But I am recieving an error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Also in my vs code terminal.I have these mentioned

```
Line 2:9:  'Subjects' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars        
Line 5:5:  Useless constructor                   no-useless-constructor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CertainPerformance answers what a useless constructor is well: basically an ESLint rule that doesn't allow you to have constructors that do nothing.

This should work for what you want to happen, though if this is the extent of the component I would place it in a functional component. In order to use this Subject array as a prop you'd have to import it in another component and pass to Description like `<Description subjects={Subjects} />`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Subjects } from './subjects';

class Description extends Component {
  render() {
    const description = Subjects.map(subjects => {
      return <h1>{subjects.title}</h1>;
    });
    return <div>{description}</div>;
  }
}

export default Description;
```

Or as a functional component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Subjects } from './subjects';

const Description = () => {
  const description = Subjects.map(subjects => {
    return <h1>{subjects.title}</h1>;
  });
  return <div>{description}</div>;
};

export default Description;
```

Answer (score 15):

A "useless constructor" is one that the linter is warning you can safely remove from the code, because it doesn't accomplish anything - if all you have is a `super` call (with the same argument the class is created with), the constructor doesn't do anything useful, because classes will already call `super` automatically, if the `constructor` isn't given:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    console.log('parent constructor running', name);
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {}

const c = new Child('bob');
```

So, the linter is telling you to delete the following lines:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
```

Since the `Subjects` identifier isn't being used anywhere, it can be removed too. Delete the line:

```
import {Subjects} from './subjects'
```

Comment: But I want the Subjects file to extract those array

Comment: Where? You aren't referencing the import anywhere in your code. If you do actually want to reference it somewhere, then you'll need to tweak your code.

Comment: But I am importing it using 'import' wouldnot that work

Comment: Yes, you're importing it - that's the problem, you aren't using the import anywhere.

Comment: But,I have used that in my map function,and i have a error of cannot read property of undefined?

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam the Subjects array you are importing isn't a prop of the Description component because you aren't passing it as a prop from another component. If you want to use the Subjects array by import you just do `Subjects.map...` instead of `this.props.Subjects.map...`

Comment: @ckifer i have this error now Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {description}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam you map your array and return your components but that last line is invalid because React can't put those `h1` tags into an object and then render it. it needs to be in an HTML element or React component.